# Strange vibration from steering wheel

Tags: toyota, steering, camry, vibration

it started about 2 days ago. When I accelerate, I feel a slight vibration under the steering wheel. When I let go of the gas pedal, the vibration gets stronger. It's not the steering wheel, feels like it came from something down at the car that send it to the steering wheel.

Right now, it doesn't affect my driving but I'm worried. What's causing the vibration, how do it fix it?

I checked the tire pressure to make sure they're ok. I also checked the power steering oil.

I have a 2004 Toyota Camry sedan. Thank  you.

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue I had especially at highway speeds and I fixed it by having my rotors skimmed, you could have your brakes inspected. Not an expert, just from my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be that I have 3 worn out tires and probably some issues with alignment as well. Car shop replaced the 3 tires and do the re-alignment, and everything is back to normal.